# Error - bitcode bundle could not be generated iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Hi i'm getting this issue while archiving the product, its working fine debug mode but getting issue while archiving lease help me

> Ld /Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/sing.app/sing normal (in target 'sing' from project 'sing')
> cd /Users/varm/Joshi/MyProjects/reactnativecli/sing-ReactApp/ios
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -target arm64-apple-ios11.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/usr/lib/swift -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/CocoaAsyncSocket -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/DoubleConversion -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/RCT-Folly -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/RCTTypeSafety -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/RNCAsyncStorage -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/RNDeviceInfo -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/RNFS -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/RNGestureHandler -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/RNReanimated -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/RNScreens -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/RNSound -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/RNVectorIcons -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-Codegen -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-Core -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-CoreModules -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTAnimation -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTBlob -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTImage -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTLinking -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTNetwork -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTSettings -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTText -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-RCTVibration -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-cxxreact -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-jsi -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-jsiexecutor -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-jsinspector -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-logger -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-perflogger -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ReactCommon -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SocketRocket -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Yoga -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/YogaKit -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/fmt -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/glog -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libevent -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/react-native-config -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/react-native-safe-area-context -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/react-native-sqlite-storage -L/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/react-native-viewpager -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/usr/lib/swift -L/Users/varm/Joshi/MyProjects/reactnativecli/sing-ReactApp/ios/Superpowered -F/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/sing.build/Release-iphoneos/sing.build/Objects-normal/arm64/sing.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/sing.build/Release-iphoneos/sing.build/Objects-normal/arm64/sing_lto.o -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -Xlinker -final_output -Xlinker /Applications/sing.app/sing -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lCocoaAsyncSocket -lDoubleConversion -lRCT-Folly -lRCTTypeSafety -lRNCAsyncStorage -lRNDeviceInfo -lRNFS -lRNGestureHandler -lRNReanimated -lRNScreens -lRNSound -lRNVectorIcons -lReact-Codegen -lReact-Core -lReact-CoreModules -lReact-RCTAnimation -lReact-RCTBlob -lReact-RCTImage -lReact-RCTLinking -lReact-RCTNetwork -lReact-RCTSettings -lReact-RCTText -lReact-RCTVibration -lReact-cxxreact -lReact-jsi -lReact-jsiexecutor -lReact-jsinspector -lReact-logger -lReact-perflogger -lReactCommon -lSocketRocket -lYoga -lYogaKit -lc++ -lc++abi -lfmt -lglog -licucore -llibevent -lreact-native-config -lreact-native-safe-area-context -lreact-native-sqlite-storage -lreact-native-viewpager -lsqlite3 -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework JavaScriptCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework UIKit -ObjC -lc++ -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreMedia -lSuperpoweredAudioIOS-iphoneos -lPods-sing -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/sing.build/Release-iphoneos/sing.build/Objects-normal/arm64/sing_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/sing.app/sing

`ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/varm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sing-gabxhsjrvxvpvidgonszrxilwwga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/sing/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libSuperpoweredAudioIOS-iphoneos.a(SuperpoweredHome.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

[image]

[image]

**I enabled bitcode**

Answer (score 0):

It seems one of your library, may be `SuperpoweredHome` is there without bitcode enabled. Archive application with bitcode enabled needs all dependent `frameworks`, `libraries` as bitcode enabled.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i already enabled bitcode for all targets, i added screenshots please check once

Comment: @JoshiG: The library in question (`SuperpoweredAudioIOS`) seems to be distributed as a binary pod. Enabling Bitcode in your project won't change that. You need to contact the developers of that library and ask for a version with Bitcode enabled.

Answer (score -1):

The error clearly says, the specific library was not built using Bitcode, so keeping Bitcode YES doesn't help.

You need to set `Skip Install` to YES and `Enable Bitcode` to Yes in framework build settings.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi i changed `Skip Install` No to `Yes` but still getting same error

Comment: Do clean build.. `npm run clean `

Comment: i did clean but still getting same issue..but if i put `Enable Bitcode` to NO then its working, is `Enable Bitcode`  NO effect other packages?

Comment: Yes you can keep it OFF, just that apple won't optimize your build for release and your app size may increase, plus it will be difficult to symboilcate crashes if they occur.